# Jetty throws exception : 'Buffer size exceeded: no line terminator' when using getParts

Tags: java, angularjs, file-upload, jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to upload a file. In the servlet when I call getParts() on request, I am getting the below error :

```
java.io.IOException: Buffer size exceeded: no line terminator
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.ReadLineInputStream.readLine(ReadLineInputStream.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.parse(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.MultiPartInputStreamParser.getParts(MultiPartInputStreamParser.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.getParts(Request.java:2290)
```

Any idea how to resolve this error ? I researched a lot and also implemented a lot of solutions, but nothing is working.

Annotated servlet with following annotation:

```
@MultipartConfig
```

When starting Jetty, added following configurations to server: (seems like TagLibConfiguration is not available in version 9.3.6.v20151106)

```
WebAppContext root = new WebAppContext();
    root.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
            new AnnotationConfiguration(), new WebXmlConfiguration(),
            new WebInfConfiguration(), //new TagLibConfiguration(),
            new PlusConfiguration(), new MetaInfConfiguration(),
            new JettyWebXmlConfiguration(),
            new FragmentConfiguration(), new EnvConfiguration() });
            ....
            ....

            ServletHolder clientServletHolder = new ServletHolder(new ClientServlet(lwServer, lwServer.getSecureAddress()
                            .getPort()));
            clientServletHolder.getRegistration().setMultipartConfig(new MultipartConfigElement(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));
            ....
            ....
```

The file that I am uploading is a binary file.

If I try below

```
            String content = IOUtils.toString(req.getInputStream(), parameters.get("charset"));
            byte[] byteArray = content.getBytes();
            System.out.println("content len : " + content.length() + "   byteArray size : " + byteArray.length);

            The output is 

            content len : 46934   byteArray size : 52864
```

And when I do a file comparison the content does not match.

The contents don't match for below either. The charset I believe is 'UTF-8'.

```
File saveFile = new File("C:\\test\\downloadedFile.bin");
            // opens input stream of the request for reading data
            InputStream inputStream = req.getInputStream();

            // opens an output stream for writing file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
            int bytesRead = -1;
            System.out.println("Receiving data...");

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            System.out.println("Data received.");
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
```

AngularJS code is as follows:

```
$('#uploadFileSubmit').click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var value = $('#uploadFileInputValue').val();

                    var f = document.getElementById('uploadFileInputValue').files[0];
                    var r = new FileReader();
                    var fileContent;
                    r.onloadend = function(e){
                        fileContent = e.target.result;
                    };
                    r.readAsBinaryString(f);
                    alert("hi !!")
                    if(value) {
                        $('#uploadFileModal').modal('hide');

                        var rsc = {};
                        rsc["id"] = scope.resource.def.id;
                        value = lwResources.getTypedValue(fileContent, scope.resource.def.type);
                        rsc["value"] = value;

                        $http({method: 'PUT', url: "api/clients/" + $routeParams.clientId + scope.resource.path, data: rsc, timeout:300000, headers:{'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
                            .success(function(data, status, headers, config) { .... }
                            .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {....});;
```

But nothing seems to resolve the error. Any idea how to resolve this error ?

Comment: I want to ask a possibly obvious question, how large are your files, and how large is your buffer? Also could you include code from the actually handling the upload/setup for the files? Also you mentioned attempting some other solutions, could you elaborate on what they were?

Comment: Where is the buffer size set ? The binary file that I am trying to upload is 21553 bytes. I will update the question with information you asked.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr size limits on `multipart/form-data` files is determined by the `@MultipartConfig` settings, the buffers in the reported error have nothing to do with that.